# How write this Function with many arguments?

Tags: algorithm

F[x1_,x2_,...,x99_]:=expr

How to write this Function in mathematica whithout complete write it?

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f];
n = 10;
Evaluate[f @@ Table[With[{s = Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]]}, Pattern[s, Blank[]]], {i, n}]] :=
  Evaluate[Plus @@ (Sin@Table[s = Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}])]

?f
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]